# WPF Image Shows only 1/3 at the top

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to take a writeablebitmap that constantly updates and render it into an Image however only the top of the image displays and the middle and bottom 2/3's are black. I think it might have something to do with PixelFormat as the writeablebitmap is bgr24 and the image is rgb24. This is what I'm currently doing.

```
int bufferSize = videoRenderer.VideoWidth * videoRenderer.VideoHeight;
byte[] frameBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
Marshal.Copy(videoRenderer.Bitmap.BackBuffer, frameBuffer, 0, bufferSize);

using (Bitmap frame = new Bitmap(videoRenderer.VideoWidth, videoRenderer.VideoHeight, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb))
{
    System.Drawing.Rectangle rect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, videoRenderer.VideoWidth, videoRenderer.VideoHeight);
    BitmapData bmpData = frame.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, frame.PixelFormat);
    Marshal.Copy(frameBuffer, 0, bmpData.Scan0, bufferSize);
    frame.UnlockBits(bmpData);
    IntPtr hBitmap = frame.GetHbitmap();
    source = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(hBitmap, IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
    DeleteObject(hBitmap);
}
```

Does something look horribly wrong, or is it most likely the pixelformat. And if the pixelformat, how would one go through each pixel in c# to swap the blue's and red's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't be just the pixel format in this case (it wouldn't cause 1/3 of the image to be rendered and the rest to be black). The difference between BGR24 and RGB24 is just a color swap.

In your case it's probably has to do with a difference in stride between the bitmap and the video source.

And as far as converting from BGR24 to RGB24 you could do it manually by locking the writable bitmap and looping over each pixel and swapping the components but that is not going to have good performance.

A much better approach would be to use the [FormatConvertedBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.formatconvertedbitmap.aspx) class.

Comment: I check the backbufferstride of the writeablebitmap and it returns 1920. The bitmapdata from the bitmap returns its stride as 1920.

Comment: If the strides match there I would check that the problem doesn't happen earlier. How is the writable bitmap updated? Maybe there is a stride difference between the source that provides the video and the writable bitmap..

Comment: videoRenderer is a custom object that holds the writeablebitmap, which is 1920.

Comment: You could verify that the problem is or isn't in the code that copies from the writable bitmap by writing to the writable bitmap a known pattern (i.e. manually draw some line pattern that you can verify on the bitmap by manually setting pixels in the writable bitmap)

Comment: It was the bufferSize... after looking at everything you suggested, I looked at how I was calculating the bufferSize and noticed it should be height * stride. Now I see the entire image as it updates. Cheers.